# Inequality for two Hardy-Littlewood Maximal Type Operators

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification, lebesgue-integral

> $\textbf{The Problem:}$ Let
>   $$Mf(x)=\sup\limits_{x\in B}\frac{1}{m(B)}\int_{B}\vert f\vert\quad\text{for }x\in\mathbb R^d$$
>   denote the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function, where the supremum is taken over all Euclidean balls $B\in\mathbb R^d$. Let $\|\cdot\|_{\ast}$ be a norm on $\mathbb R^d$ and define
>   $$\tilde{M}f(x)=\sup\limits_{r>0}r^{-d}\int_{\mathbb R^d}\vert f(x+y)\vert\mathbf1_{\|y\|_{\ast}\leq r}dy.$$
>   Prove that there exists a constant $c\in(0,\infty)$ depending only on $d$ and $\|\cdot\|_{\ast}$ such that $Mf(x)\leq c\tilde{M}f(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb R^d$ and $f\in L^{1}_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R^d).$

$\textbf{My Thoughts:}$ Let $B\subset\mathbb R^d$ be an arbitrary but fixed ball containing $x$. Then we can choose a ball $B_{r}'(x)$ centered at $x$ with twice the radius of $B$. Then we have with $m(B_{1}(0))=v,$
\begin{align*}\frac{1}{m(B)}\int_{B}\vert f\vert\leq\frac{1}{m(B)}\int_{B'}\vert f\vert\leq\frac{2^d}{m(B')}\int_{B'}\vert f\vert=\frac{2^d r^{-d}}{v}\int_{B'}\vert f\vert.
\end{align*}
Since $\mathbb R^d$ is a finite dimensional normed vector space, all norms on it are equivalent, that is there are positive constants such that $c_{1}\|y\|_{\ast}\leq\|y\|_{2}$. It follows that
$$\large\frac{2^d r^{-d}}{v}\int_{B'}\vert f\vert\leq \frac{2^{d}r^{-d}}{v}\int_{\|y\|_{\ast}\leq\frac{r}{c}}\vert f(x+y)\vert dy,$$
so putting $c=\frac{2^d}{v}$ and taking supremums we have what we need.

---

Is my proof above correct? Any comments are welcomed, be it about the style, lack of details, and most important, the correctness.

Thank you for your time.